# vue js laravel cors error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

ребят не как не могу поправит cors error вот что написал
на бекенду
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл index.php не помогло
создал middelware
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тоже не помогло
на фронту запрос так идет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и ошибка corsa
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй открыть все методы со стороны `laravel` в прослойке `CORS`

```
return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://front.itr.am')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: Попробовал не работает, кажется что из за сервера, на другом сервере сделал запрос на апи все работало тут нет (

Comment: А что тебе говорит postman при попытке постучаться ?

Comment: Postman получает все нормально, поправили http меняли на https все поправился спасибо большое